# Taylor series of reduction version

Tags: taylor-expansion

I know that Taylor series for $f(x)$ at $x_0$ is
$$
f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0) + \frac{f^{(2)}(x_0)}{2!}(x-x_0)^2 + \frac{f^{(3)}(x_0)}{3!}(x-x_0)^3 + \frac{f^{(4)}(x_0)}{4!}(x-x_0)^4 + \cdots
$$
where $f^{(k)}$ implies the $k$-th derivative of $f$.

---

Sometimes, we shorten the equation above using big-$O$ or small-$o$ notation, which are:

Let $g$ be a real-valued function defined in some neighborhood of $0\in\Bbb{R}$, with $g(x)\ne0$ if $x\ne0$. Let $f:\Omega\to\Bbb{R}$ be defined in a domain $\Omega\subset\Bbb{R}$ that include $0$. Then,

1. $f(x)=O(g(x))$ to mean that the quotient $\displaystyle\frac{|f(x)|}{|g(x)|}$ is bounded near $0$; that is, there exist numbers $K\gt0$ and $\delta\gt0$ such that if $|x|\lt\delta$, $x\in\Omega$, then $\displaystyle\frac{|f(x)|}{|g(x)|}\le K$.
2. $f(x)=o(g(x))$ to mean that $$\lim_{x\to0,x\in\Omega} \frac{|f(x)|}{|g(x)|}=0$$

Then,
$$
f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0) + \frac{f^{(2)}(x_0)}{2!}(x-x_0)^2 + O(|x-x_0|^3)\\
or\\
f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0) + \frac{f^{(2)}(x_0)}{2!}(x-x_0)^2 + o(|x-x_0|^2)
$$

---

However, the textbook I am reading expresses Taylor series expansion of $f$ at $x_0$ as
$$
f(x)=f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0) + \frac{f''(x^*)}{2}(x-x_0)^2
$$
where $x^*$ lies between $x_0$ and $x$.

---

Please let me understand why this expression is just.
Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: $(1)$ Your expression for $o(g(x))$ is wrong.  $(2)$ You mean $o(|x-x_0|^2)$.  $(3)$ To answer your actual question: your textbook is giving you a formula for a Taylor *polynomial* with the error term -- not the Taylor series.  Though related, Taylor polynomials and Taylor series are not the same thing.

Comment: You should look at [analytic is much stronger than $C^\infty$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function). Every $C^k$ function has a Taylor expansion of order $k$, every $C^\infty$ function has a Taylor expansion of every order, while only analytic functions have a Taylor series converging to the function (on some neighborhood of the point). The derivation of the Taylor expansion uses integration by parts, and the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @Bye_World I edited my question more precisely. Sorry for using Taylor series mixed with Taylor polynomial. And I know $x^*$ is derived from some error term. I want to know how to justify equality of last equation as well as how we can say that $x^*$ lies between $x0$ and $x$.

Comment: @user1952009 Thank you for answering but I want to know that if $x^*$ lies between $x_0$ and $x$, $\displaystyle\frac{f''(x^*)}{2}(x-x_0)^2 = \frac{f''(x_0)}{2!}(x-x_0)^2+\frac{f^{(3)}(x_0)}{3!}(x-x_0)^3+\cdots$. That is, I want to prove that there exists a value laid between $x_0$ and $x$ satisfying the equation.

Comment: I meant the mean value theorem . See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Proofs . And I don't get your last sentence, nor I don't think you understood what I wrote above (analytic vs $C^\infty$ vs $C^k$, Taylor expansion vs Taylor series)

Comment: @user1952009 Thank you very much. I found it!!